# How to make these complicated charts in Xcode?

Tags: swift, xcode

I got an array of specific data for each 5 minutes with a string of colours type of 4 colours. The first one will be a daily chart, while the second one will be the weekly chart.
[image]

[image]

I found a good library here `https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts` , but it's not the design i wanted. How does one implement these charts ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use CoreGraphics, and do it on your own. It is simple, but you should look for WWDC video which show how Apple make graphs.

Answer (score 1):

Both of these graphs could be drawn with [Core Plot](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot). The top one would use trading range plots and the bottom one would use scatter plots with an area fill. Both graphs need four plots, one for each color.